# How tall was Chava?

Tags: midrash, adam, vaeschanan, literalism, eve-chava

Rashi [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=54044&st=&pgnum=40&hilite=) brings a Midrash that Adam Harishon's height was from earth until the Heavens. Based on the Midrash, was Chava that tall as well? Otherwise it would have been quite difficult to be married to each other.

Comment: Perhaps the midrash is not true, or is true but not literal...

Comment: @mevaqesh Don't play dull. Clearly the question is asking according to those who hold they are literal.

Comment: @Don what are you taking about "they are literal" who is talking _them_" I was talking about the intent of a particular source; that the OP asked about. Not about a genre of literature that the OP didn't ask about. No need to hurl accusations...

Comment: @mevaqesh Not my intention, sorry. All I was trying to say is that in these sorts of questions it's reasonable to assume they're taking the Midrash literally, as the question doesn't start otherwise.

Comment: Indeed. My intent was to prompt him to question the assumption, and or buttress it; to the benefit of the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh my question is not whether the Midrash is literal or not. That is beyond my pay grade. My question is whatever the Midrash meant for Adam, did the same apply to Chava as well, be it literal or whatever.

Comment: @Earl you seem to be talking to Doniel. I understand fully that you aren't asking if it is literal. However, the difficulty in marriage seems predicated on a literal read. If he wasn't literally a giant there is no reason to assume conflict.

Comment: I don't see why a giant can't marry a dwarf or vice versa. If anything, if Chava were "short" she just has to tell her husband to get to the top of the tree where the best fig leaves are!

Comment: There is a similar account about Og telling Avraham about Lot in order that Avraham would die in the war and Og would then marry Sarah.

Comment: @DanF An eight-foot giant could marry a four-foot dwarf. But unless Adam had a proportionally miniscule member, as a giant of Chazal's descriptive magnitude he would be unable to engage in intercourse with Chava - which he surely did.

Comment: @Chaim The only place in Tanac"h that I know of where a giant's height is numerically specified is the description of Goliath. Og's height is indirectly described via the size of his bed. Thus, it' s possible that regardig everyone else, our concept of giants looking like Shreck or the "beanstalk Giant" etc. could be way off regarding the giants described in the Torah. It may all be relative to what was at that time. Adam could have been 2 meters tall and Chava 1.5 meters tall, for all we know.

Comment: Ah, so is this where the whole "tall guys always end up with short girls" thing originated? Fascinating!